# October CMS - extend page to have an associated image

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

What are the best and clean possible ways to extend functionality for including an associated image to each page object (CMS page or StaticPage), adding a corresponding upload widget to the page's configuration in the OctoberCMS backend?

(Additionally, and just as an aside: In what way can one add an associated image to a site's theme?)

Comment: I think there is no need to keep this on hold anymore after the question has been edited to accomodate a wide but specific range of answers. Though I suppose that all possible cases have been covered already in the most "canonical" way, which makes this a nice little reference Q&A now.
Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For CMS pages, add a register() method to your Plugin.php file:

```
public function register()
{
    Event::listen('backend.form.extendFields', function($widget) {
        if (!$widget->model instanceof \Cms\Classes\Page) return;

        $widget->addTabFields([
            'settings[image_filet]' => [
                'label' => 'Page image',
                'tab' => 'Image',
                'field' => 'settings[image_file]',
                'type' => 'mediafinder',
                'comment' => 'Image url is available via the page settings under the name of image_file'
            ],
        ], 'primary');
    });
}
```

And the value is available via this.page.image_file Twig value

Comment: Great, this looks like it may be the more "canonical" way to use ```$widget->model``` instead of ```$form->config->model``` as I used in this other answer. (I guess that the ```$form->config->model``` way is somehow deprecated, as it seems to appear more in older plugins' code.) Do you happen to know what the exact technical difference is between the two, though? I have no idea.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks very much. Seems to be a small type of image_filet (?), though, but this works really well!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to attach an image (or file) on front-end.

One is to use the attachments system which is in OctoberCMS Documentation that requires to be in a plugin and I guess you don't want this way.

The other way is to make it in the front-end theme customization form.

Simply in your OctoberCMS theme there's a file `theme.yaml` and you can add this code to it:

```
name: ''
description: ''
author: 'Ahmed Essam'
homepage: ''
code: my_theme
name: 'My Theme'
form:
    fields:
        my_image:
            type: fileupload
            mode: image
            label: Upload my image
```

So anywhere in your front-end theme you can access this image by calling:

```
{{ this.theme.my_image.getPath() }}
```

You can upload the image in the backend by going to Backend -> Front-end theme -> Customize

Answer (score 1):

Do try to extend Rainlab's [page plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages) or CMS pages?

For static pages plugin, to add a tab on the settings section of a static page, you need to create a plugin that extends Rainlab's pages plugin and add a tabbed field using the extendFields function. Here's an example of extension. This code must be placed in the Plugin.php file of your plugin.

```
public function boot()
{
    Event::listen('backend.form.extendFields', function($widget) {

        $objectPath = trim(Request::input('objectPath'));

        if (
            !$widget->getController() instanceof \RainLab\Pages\Controllers\Index ||
            !$widget->model instanceof \RainLab\Pages\Classes\Page
        ) {
            return;
        }

        $widget->addTabFields([
            'viewBag[image_file]' => [
                'label' => 'Attach image to this page',
                'tab' => 'Image',
                'field' => 'viewBag[image_file]',
                'type' => 'mediafinder',
                'comment' => 'Image url is available via the viewBag with the name of image_file'
            ]
        ]);
    });
}
```

Then in your layout file, partials or CMS pages you can display the image with this code :

```
<img src="{{ staticPage.extraData['image_file']|_media }}">
```

And don't forget to inject dependencies in your Plugin.php file:

```
use Event;
use Backend;
use Request;
use RainLab\Pages\Classes\Controller;
```

Comment: Great swift answer!
Guess it would be difficult to extend the core through a plugin to make something like this possible even with CMS pages? Hmm, I'll try and see...

(BTW. please support the [proposal for an OctoberCMS stackexchange section](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97119/octobercms/), and I hope I wont't get banned here for advertising :~) Okay, I'm really taking chances here... )

Comment: Very useful answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after we have good canonical answers for [adding an associated image to your theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41046865/7048200) or [adding an associated image to a StaticPage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41047270/7048200), I'll cover the remaining case of **adding an associated image to a CMS page:**

Create a plugin by running `php artisan create:plugin yourname.nameofyourplugin` in your October app directory.

Edit the file `{% october app root %}/plugins/yourname/nameofyourplugin/Plugin.php`, adding the following to the plugin's `boot()` method:

```
public function boot()
{
    Event::listen('backend.form.extendFields', function($form) {
        if (get_class($form->config->model) == 'Cms\Classes\Page')
        {
            $form->addFields([
                    'settings[associated_image]' => [
                        'label'   => 'Associated image for this page',
                        'type'    => 'mediafinder',
                        'mode'    => 'image',
                        'span'    => 'auto',
                        'comment' => 'na logo alter',
                    ]
            ]);
        }
    });
}
```

And you are done.

**(Edit: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41048763/7048200) answer for a perhaps more canonical way. it may be that the `$form->config->model` way of accessing the model class attribute is deprecated, and it's now more en vogue to use `$widget->model`, as I have adapted this from a somewhat older piece of code. Not really sure about the technical difference though, so I'll just leave this as an alternative.)**

Now you find a widget to add an associated image to any of your standard CMS pages.

This extends the fields associated with the `Cms\Classes\Page` class, found in `{% october app root %}/cms/classes/page/fields.yaml`, adding an **associated_image** field to it. By including this field in the `settings` array (i.e. choosing the field name `settings[associated_image]` for the new form field, we make sure that this field can be set in the [config section](https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/themes#configuration-section) of your page template (i.e. by adding the line `associated_image = "/path/to/my/cool/image.jpg"` at the top) and is then accessible by twig through the `page` object, i.e. by writing `{{ page.associated_image }}` in twig.

So then, after adding the associated image to any CMS page, you could put something like `<img src="{{ page.associated_image | media}}">` (or `{% if (page.associated_image | length) > 0 %}<img src="{{ page.associated_image | media}}">{% endif %}` to check if the image exists first) on your page to include the image that you added.

(Note that we use the [MediaFinder](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-mediafinder) form widget here for the image, which saves the uploaded image's path relative to the `{% october app root %}/storage/media` directory. So we need the `{{ ... | media }}` twig filter to get the correct image url in the page.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!